# React Native 0.71 main.jsbundle seems encrypted?

Tags: react-native, ixguard

Since React Native 0.71 the main.jsbundle seems encrypted?

Or should we see it as the binary hermes bundle?

Can someone explain why the main.jsbundle is not in ES6 javascript specification anymore?  Or give some references to an explanation?  Cannot find any in the release notes.

We use guardsquare to obfuscate the main.jsbundle bundle, but thats not possible anymore, or is it not needed anymore because it's a binary bundle?

[image: main.jsbundle]